# How to get the value of the selection field other than the key in q-web reports odoo 12?

Tags: odoo-12, qweb

I have a selection field like

```
field = fields.Selection([('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B')],string='Test')
```

When i tried fetching the selected element in the selection field the key 'a' is getting printed to the pdf, i needs to print the 'A'

`<t t-esc="med['field']"/>` #med is one2many line connecting model A to the B,i'm trying to fetch the datas from model B(Notebook),

Comment: Here you will find your answer https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/showing-the-string-value-of-a-selection-field-in-qweb-report-92686

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about older versions, but atleast in Odoo 13.0 just use `t-field` instead of `t-esc` so Odoo will get the right value for you. Simple example:

`<span t-field="med.field" />`

Comment: Yes probably back to version 9.0 or 8.0, but i didn't check it.

Comment: Works very well in version 16.0 thank you.